# I am getting error in php mysqli function saying data base not found

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, wamp

Using wamp server version 3.2.0

**The Error-**

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'mywebsite' in E:\wamp64\www\biren\php_DB_linking\2_Linking_to_DB.php on line 7

I have the data base created in PHP Myadmin in my local host
[image]

constantly showing this error
[image]

```
<?php
$servername ="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="mywebsite";//name of my DB
//creating the connection.
$connect= new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);//Error line
if($connect->connect_error){
    die("connection failed".$connect->connect_error);
}
else {
    echo "connection done";
}?>
```

Comment: From your search bar It appears that you have created db with name `mywebsite` on your local machine but you are trying to access it on another machine.

Comment: @OmarAbbas all 127.x addresses are a local machine tho